# Can you simplify a coordinate

Tags: quadratics

Can you simplify $(-6,-36)$ to $(-1,-6)$ if the first coordinate is the min value of a quadratic graph. The equation is $y = x^2 + 12x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, these are two different points in the (Cartesian) plane.  If you draw this graph, you will see that the minimum value is attended at $(-6,-36)$ and the point $(-1,-6)$ is not even on the graph.

Comment: Thank you very much it has helped me a lot

Comment: You're welcome =)

Comment: BTW what is the Cartesian plane?

Comment: It's the standard coordinate system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system

Comment: Cheers for all your help :)

Comment: @WhosDench - [The origin of Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes#Mathematical_legacy)